# How to extract triplicates or higher records in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS, is there an easy way to extract records from a data set that have more than 2 occurrences.

The DUPS command gives duplicates, but how to get triplicates and higher?
For example, in this dataset:

```
col1   col2  col3   col4   col5  
1        2    3       4     5  
1        2    3       5     7  
1        2    3       4     8  
A        B    C       D     E  
A        B    C       S     W
```

The first 3 columns are my key columns. So in my output, I only want first 3 rows(triplicates) but not last 2 rows (duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using proc sql pretty easily.  The below example will keep all rows from the table that are triplicates (or higher).

Create some sample data:

```
data have;
  input col1 $
        col2 $
        col3 $ 
        col4 $ 
        col5 $
        ;
  datalines;
1        2    3       4     5  
1        2    3       5     7  
1        2    3       4     8  
A        B    C       D     E  
A        B    C       S     W 
;
run;
```

First identify the triplicates. I'm assuming you want triplicates (or above), and that you're grouping on the first 3 columns:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table tmp as
  select col1, col2, col3, count(*)
  from have
  group by 1,2,3
  having count(*) ge 3
  ;
quit;
```

Then use the tmp table we just created to filter against the original dataset via a join.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select a.*
  from have a
  join tmp  b  on b.col1 = a.col1
              and b.col2 = a.col2
              and b.col3 = a.col3
  ;
quit;
```

These 2 steps could be combined into a single step with a subquery if you desired but I'll leave that up to you.

**EDIT :**  Keith's answer provides a shorthand way to combine these 2 steps into a single step.

Comment: Thanks. This is how I did it. I was hoping if there was a single command like TRUPS or something

Comment: @Victor Sorry I don't think there is.  Source: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146878.htm

Comment: @Robert Why not just use the first query?  This will return the required rows without needing the 2nd step (I've just edited my answer as I realised I'd only included col1 in the `group by`)

Comment: @Keith Sometimes you want to see the original record in it's entirety.  For example, if I was looking for an email address that had multiple orders, I may not just be interested in the actual email address, but in the details of the orders themselves.  This is the typical use-case for me when I'm doing this kind of thing.  Not sure about the OP.

Comment: @Robert You can still do `select *` to extract the full record, along with `group by` and `having`.  This is one instance where SAS Sql is different from most other flavours

Comment: @Keith Did not know this.  Thanks.  Updated answer to mention yours.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `proc sql` for this, taking advantage of the `group by` and `having` clauses.  Even though it's one step of code, it does require 2 passes of the data in the background, however I believe this needs to be the case whichever method you use.

```
data have;
input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $ col5 $;
datalines;
1        2    3       4     5
1        2    3       5     7
1        2    3       4     8
A        B    C       D     E
A        B    C       S     W
;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select * from have
group by col1,col2,col3
having count(*)>2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the data step solution: a double DoW loop, first counting the rows then outputting when >= 3.  This actually only passes through the data once after the sort (a double DoW loop lists two reads, but they're buffered so the file is only read once).

This solution runs slightly faster on my machine than the SQL solution; not by much, but slightly.  On a dataset with 12.5MM rows, of which about 1/4 are in the final triplicate+ dataset, total time (sort plus datastep) is about 10s real/13.5s CPU, while Keith's SQL is 12.5 real/15 CPU.  I suspect this solution is always slightly faster than the SQL solution, but in a lot of cases is not much faster, unless you can skip the sort but the dataset isn't actually sorted (SQL will only skip the sort if the dataset is marked as sorted).

The NOUNIQUEKEY only works in 9.3+, and is sometimes helpful - if you have a lot of unique records and only few duplicates (with 2+ rows), it will speed up the final read.  It will take longer to do the sort, though, so it's only worth it if that final read speed-up is helpful.  In the below it's very slightly helpful, but not by much; it turns execution from 5s/5s RT to 6s/3s, but at the same CPU time - 8/5.5 (normal) vs 10.5/3 (nounique).

```
data have;
input col1   $ col2  $ col3   $ col4   $ col5  $;
datalines;
1        2    3       4     5  
1        2    3       5     7  
1        2    3       4     8  
A        B    C       D     E  
A        B    C       S     W 
;;;;
run;

proc sort nouniquekey data=have out=have_dups;  *nouniquekey is 9.3+, helps optimize sometimes- it is optional;
by col1 col2 col3;
run;

data want;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.col3);
    set have_dups;
    by col1 col2 col3;
    count_row=sum(count_row,1);
  end;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.col3);
    set have_dups;
    by col1 col2 col3;
    if count_row ge 3 then output;
  end;
run;
```